# Starting a rails test server with Cypress on CI

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, cypress

I can run cypress locally if I start a rails server using `RAILS_ENV=test rails server`, and then running the `cypress run` but I am lost on how to do this on CI.

I'm using SemaphoreCI which allows me to have setup commands before I run rspec:

```
$ bundle install
$ npm install
$ bundle exec rake db:create db:migrate db:test:prepare --trace
```

Followed by the actual jobs:

```
$ bundle exec rspec
```

According to [cypress](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/exec.html#Commands-Must-Exit), I can't use `cy.exec()` to start a rails server and I can't run `rails server` as my last setup command since it won't exit. How else could I start a a test server on CI so that I can run `cypress run`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up adding `RAILS_ENV=test bundle exec rails server -p 3000 -d` so it runs in the background, then `kill -9 $(cat tmp/pids/server.pid)` for the after job command (once rspec/cypress are done running)

Answer (score 2):

On CircleCi I added this step to the config.

**.cicleci\config.yml**

```
  - run:
      name: Rails Server
      command: bundle exec rails server -e test -b 0.0.0.0 -p 5002
      background: true
```

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is to use the [start-server-and-test](https://github.com/bahmutov/start-server-and-test) library to have a command that starts and waits for your web server then runs cypress.

Add the following line to your `package.json`:

```
 {
    "scripts": {
      "test:e2e:ci": "start-server-and-test develop http://localhost:8000 cy:run"
    }
  }
```

Then have your CI run `yarn test:e2e:ci` command.